# Do an action when the map is moved

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I would like to do an action when the map is moved, I tried this feature but it does not work:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Hey"
    alert.message = "Map Move"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Working!!")
    alert.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you set mapView.delegate? If not so, `regionWillChangeAnimated` method is NOT called.

example.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

ref. My MKMapView sample code
https://github.com/koogawa/MKMapViewSample

Comment: can you take a look at my post. Its similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131213/regiondidchange-called-several-times-on-app-load-swift

Answer (score 0):

In my code I have a very similar answer to the answer above but i add a self. first so it looks like this

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```